# error_msg is not defined in node js , ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

First, I was facing error req.flash not define then I remove that error
and add content to messages.ejs file then is receiving an error regarding all the types of messages like success and errors not defined.

I have a login.ejs file as here I include message.ejs file
Here is my messages.ejs file as

```
<% if(typeof errors != 'undefined'){ %> <% errors.forEach(function(error) 
{ 
%>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <%= error.msg %>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
<% }); %>
<% } %>

<% if(error_msg != ''){ %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <%= error_msg %>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
<% } %>

<% if(error != ''){ %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <%= error %>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I'm facing this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `error.msg` instead of `error_msg`? You use both

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know without looking at your other files, but I suspect you are getting this error because error_msg is not spelled correctly in your app.js file, or it is not in your app.js file. You should add this line in your app.js file:

```
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    next();
});
```